# Rehashing hashtable

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable

When I debug I find out that in the temporary hashtable - 'hashtable2' no elements are inserted. All other parts of the hashtable code work.

I am not sure why the no values get inserted into hashtable2

```
void rehash(struct HashTable* hashTable, int keySize)
{
    int i;
    struct HashElement* current;
    int i2 = 0;
    struct List* word;
    struct List* key;
    struct HashTable* hashTable2 = hashTableConstructor(33524, keySize);

    hashTable->keySize = keySize; 

    for(i=0; i<hashTable->numBuckets; i++) //for every bucket
    {
        current = hashTable->buckets[i];

        //'walk' the linked list of HashElements in the bucket
        while( current != NULL )
        { //till the end of hash table
            word = listConstructor();
            key = listConstructor();
            word = current->value;

            for(i2 = 0; i2<keySize; i2++)
            {
                listAdd(key, tolower(getCharacter(word,i2)));
            }

            insert(hashTable2, word, key);
            listDestructor(key);
            listDestructor(word);
            current = current->next;
        }

    }



    hashTableDestructor(hashTable);


    hashTable = hashTableConstructor(33524, keySize);
    hashTable = hashTable2;

}
```

Comment: Hint: `hashTable = hashTable2`; means *nothing* to the caller of your function. It was passed by value, and the caller retains that value. And the line immediately previous to that is your textbook basic memory leak. This isn't Java or C#. And since the *vast* majority of the code used to manage your hash table is *not* present in this post, we have no [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with.

Comment: How can I hashTable = hashTable2 then?

Comment: can I do it with memcpy?

Comment: There honestly isn't enough data in this question to know how to properly perform the action you're trying to do. We don't know what `HashTable`, `HashElement` or `List` are. We don't know how they're fundamentally utilized in your hash table scheme. I could *guess* that `*hashTable = *hashTable2;` might work, but your memory management needs significant review (I already pointed out one leak), and this site isn't about *guesses*; it's about *answers*. To provide a conclusive answer we need information to draw informed conclusions, and currently we don't have that.

Comment: Please bare in mind that I am a beginner... If List is an arraylist data structure what are the other possible solutions?

Comment: @harleydave22: Without seeing the code that defines `struct HashTable`, `struct HashElement`, and `struct List`, we do not have enough information to help you. What you are currently asking is similar to asking which kind of fuel to put into your vehicle, without specifying whether it is a car, an aeroplane, or a nuclear subterrene. (Even then, we'd need to know the exact make and model!) Without specifics, we are blind, and thus unable to help you. It is up to you to give us enough information for us to be able to help you.